# Keyboard shortcut for ruby script

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys, ruby

I have some problem here when I'm trying to make a keyboard shortcut for my ruby script.
So the first step I've do for it was to make a alias and add that command for alias on file .bashrc

```
alias note="~/ums.rb > note.txt && gedit note.txt && rm note.txt"
```

Now I can access my command using just the alias.
After that I've try to make a new keyboard shortcut, so I've enter on Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and add that command as shortcut

```
gnome-terminal -e "note"
```

But I don't know why... nothing happened when I use the shorcut.

Can anyone help me please? :D

Comment: Try `source ~/.bashrc` this should reload the .bashrc file so that you alias work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases are not available to the GUI shortcut tools. They don't read `.bashrc`, for one thing and the don't run the normal bash shell anyway. Aliases only work on the command line.

So, instead of using the alias, just make a shortcut that launches a shell and runs the command itself:

```
bash -c "~/ums.rb > note.txt && gedit note.txt && rm note.txt"
```

If your ruby script relies on variables set in your `~/.bashrc`, source it:

```
bash -c ". ~/.bashrc && ~/ums.rb > note.txt && gedit note.txt && rm note.txt"
```

Comment: Thx man, but that works just partial. Because if I will put that as shortcut... I will obtain that result `nokogiri gem not installed
   gem install nokogiri` but in command line works fine

Comment: @Vildnex well yes, that's because you need things that you are setting in your shell's configuration files. Please [edit] your question and explain that/. We need to know all relevant details. In the meantime, try changing the command to `bash -c ". ~/.bashrc && ~/ums.rb > note.txt && gedit note.txt && rm note.txt"`

Comment: Thx man, rly thx, that second command works fine :D